Position of equipment in 3D Simulation
Currently, I am modeling a process where I use machines (agents) positioned at specific locations on a layout. these locations are represented by nodes. I assigned my machines to the nodes as represented in the following layout (fig.1),
but when I tried to simulate the model, I noticed a difference of position (fig.2). Equipments are not on the node. What can I do in this case?
, 
